# Arduino controlled remote for an rc car. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: remote-control, electronics

I have an Osepp Mega 2560 (Arduino Compatible) which I'm trying to use to run a RC Car from the remote control.

> [image: http://dwkd.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/arduino-project/]

Can someone please explain how do I need to connect the pins from Osepp to the remote board.

**The setup** (please look at image for bolded details):
 - Osepp 5v Power pin going to the **Positive** (see red wire)
 - Osepp GND pin going to the **Negative** (Black wire)
 - Osepp Pin 13 (pwm) going to the **signal to drive forward** (bottom of the board).

**The Code**

```
int led = 13;

void setup() {                
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(led, LOW);   
  delay(10000);               
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);    
  delay(10000);              
}
```

**The Problem**
I expect that after 10 seconds the remote will start sending a signal to move forward.
In actuality the signal gets sent right away, even though the pin is set to LOW.

The "**signal to drive forward**" spot where I soldered a wire from pin 13 is where power gets sent once you press down the joystick (also highlighted in the pic) and complete the circuit.

**FYI**
I am not trying to do any modulation, pin 13 may have been a poor choice.
I do not have any kits nor manuals, just winging it
The joystick for the forward action is actually suppose to be top left(missing in this case but you can see the circuit) and not the one highlighted in the picture

Comment: So you have it wired, but you want to know how to create a PWM signal?

Comment: Yeah, this is a confusing question... please provide more detail about what your pin is connected to, include the code you think is driving that pin, why you think it should be PWM, and why you think it's not. If you're connected directly to a motor, PWM might act as a simple DC speed controller, but you're gonna need some code to do that, and the concept of ON and OFF and HIGH and LOW no longer apply. Makes me think you're using the wrong code.

Comment: Also, if you're working with a specific kit, please provide a link to that kit, and page numbers or something to indicate the step you're having trouble with, from the manual of said kit.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am writing up more details. Remember to look at the picture. On the step i mentioned "Osepp Pin 13 (pwm) going to the signal to drive forward"  In the picture you'll find the "signal to drive forward" mark on the circuit board where I'm connecting to

Comment: Why does it look like the top-left (button removed) pad is connected to the "move forward" pin. And from that, it looks like it gets pulled to ground when the button is pressed.

Comment: You're right, that is the pad for move forward. Any thoughts on how to connect it to the Arduino?

Comment: Totally the wrong code. Why did you think the "Blink" code would run an RC car? That code is for blinking an LED - that's what it does. It doesn't do something else. The "Blink" program does not send a PWM signal down the line. If your device expects a PWM signal, this code won't do anything reasonable.

Comment: OH also... this is more of a "project" than a "question" and it may be more appropriate to use the Arduino forum. http://forum.arduino.cc/

Comment: My logic here was:
The joystick completes that portion of the circuit when pressed so I measured how much power goes through the circuit into the microcontroller pin when the joystick is pressed. Pin 13 delivers roughly the same voltage when set to HIGH so I assumed that by 'enabling' the pin (setting OUTPUT = HIGH) you would deliver that much power. One would expect that. However, to my surprise, the power is always there regardless of the state of pin 13 (HIGH or LOW) so my question is why? and how can I control that?

Comment: Eh... well, you're getting confused pretty badly here. Power, voltage, and current don't really work that way. If you send too much current through your Arduino pin, it's gonna fry that pin and probably the ATmega chip too. We need to work this out on the forum, this isn't something we can give you a quick answer for. You need an intro to microcontroller electronics first. Have you done all the little projects in the starter kit? You really need to do those... I've been doing this stuff for 30 years and I loved this kit - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf4qosqpv3A

Comment: If you go to the Arduino Forum, I will help you, along with the rest of the community. I've done videos to help people with things on there - that's how much we care.

Comment: ok I will check out the kit and then come back to update the question and perhaps move it to the forum if it's still unclear. Thanks

Comment: Added to the Arduino forum http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=241237.0      Thanks

Comment: As this has now been asked and discussed on the Arduino forum, and the original question is not very clear, I am going to close this question. I'm going to close this question. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!